# sns.histplot - percentage on the y-axis

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, histogram

How to display the percentage on the y-axis, please? Doesn't stat='frequency' do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = [6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 2, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 2, 7, 3, 1, 5, 2, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 1, 9, 2, 1, 4]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.histplot(data, discrete=True, kde=False, stat='frequency') 

plt.show()
```

Comment: As the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) states, `'percent'` may be what you want.

Comment: First, note that if you created the `ax` before calling `sns.histplot`, you're expected to pass it as parameter.  You can use `stat='percent'` to show the percentages (or, as the histogram is discrete, `stat='density()` to show the y-axis as fraction of 1).  To show a percentage sign, you could use `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter(100))`